# How can i fix the error so that i could use insertion sort

Tags: java, for-loop, debugging, insertion-sort

I was trying to create a random array that takes in a user input and prints that amount of random values

for example if i put in 5 it would create an array of [3,4,5,6,6]

and then i tried use insertion sort so it could rearrange the values in the correct order from smallest value to largest value, however i kept getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    j cannot be resolved to a variable
```

and that error was on the line `result[j+1] = key;`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Size of Random Number");
        int n = input.nextInt(); 
        Random random = new Random(); 
        int[] result = random.ints(n, 0, 10).toArray();
        Arrays.stream(result).forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println("\n");
        
       
        int len = result.length;
        for(int i=1; i<len; i++) {
            int key = result[i];
            for (int j=i-1; (j >= 0 && result[j] > key); j--) { 
                result[j + 1] = result[j];  
            }  
            result[j+1] = key;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: `j` only exists in the loop in which it is declared.

Comment: i tried to put it back into the loop, however, it wouldn't do the insertion sort

Comment: If you need it outside of the loop, then declare it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1; i<len; i++) {
        int key = result[i];
        int j;
        // you should declare a variable outside of the for loop in such cases,
        // because if you declare it within the for loop it will be locally scoped within that for loop and not available outside it.
        for (j=i-1; (j >= 0 && result[j] > key); j--) {
            result[j + 1] = result[j];
        }
        result[j+1] = key;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
```

You can read more about scope [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope) .

> 4. Loop Scope
>
> If we declare a variable inside a loop, it will have a loop scope and will only be available inside the loop:

Comment: Hi @Manuj, please update your answer to include a quote from the page you referenced - so in the event that page goes missing the insight you are trying to suggest isn't lost.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback , I did not use a quote from the page , I left it there if they wanted to read more about scope in java.